# Cannot play local audio file on UIWebView

Tags: ios, css, objective-c, audio, uiwebview

I am trying to play local audio file in UIWebView. I use for it  HTML5 tag:

```
[myWeb loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div style='clear: both;'></div>
    <div style='width: 570px; height: 100px; padding-top: 25px; overflow: hidden;'>
        <audio controls> <source src=\"%@\"></audio></div>", filePath] baseURL:nil];
```

If I use

```
local path: NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound_test16" ofType:@"wav"];
```

it writes: "Cannot play audio file.", but if I use

```
NSString* filePath = @"http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/test.mp3";
```

It plays successfully.

Why I cannot play local file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've spotted your problem.  You need to prefix the local file with the file protocol:

```
[myWeb loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div style='clear: both;'></div>
    <div style='width: 570px; height: 100px; padding-top: 25px; overflow: hidden;'>
        <audio controls> <source src=\"file:%@\"></audio></div>", filePath] baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Yes, it's help, thank you, but no need slash:
    [myWeb loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div style='clear: both;'></div><div style='width: 570px; height: 100px; padding-top: 25px; overflow: hidden;'><audio controls> <source src=\"file:%@\"></audio></div>", filePath] baseURL:nil];

Comment: @wottle - I am facing same issue but for only few audio files especially with .wav format. As i observed this is not happening for all files. I got one .wav file which is not playing and showing the error "Cannot play audio file". Do you have any idea why is this happening

Comment: If it's working for other files, including other .wav files, the only thing that comes to mind is that it could be something corrupt in the .wav file that some players can handle, but the built-in iOS wav processor cannot.